# SSPI negotiation result

Tags: windows, kerberos, sspi, ntlmv2

I cannot find what SSPI function should I have to call to get the type of protocol that Windows picked up after the `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` with `Negotiate` option... !?

Comment: How does kerberos and ntlm relate to Negotiate auth scheme?

Comment: The whole point of Negotiate is that it allows SSPI to negotiate either NTLM or Kerberos (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378748(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once negotiation is complete you call [`QueryContextAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the negotiated context and specify `SECPKG_ATTR_PACKAGE_INFO`.

You will already have the negotiated attributes and context expiry details from the last call to `InitializeSecurityContext()` or `AcceptSecurityContext()`